# Merge MS Word documents in github

Tags: github, ms-word, docx

I have a github repository and with a collaborator I am working on two version of the same Word document (.docx file).

I created a branch, but when I ask to make the merge between the two files, I cannot find the differences between the two files, as in the
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98oKG.png).
Clicking on view, the message I receive in the middle of the page is:
*Sorry about that, but we can’t show files that are this big right now.*

When I tried to make the merge, the file of the branch version was simply overwritten on the master one (something that I do not want).

How can I merge them, checking all the new edits?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean merging parts of text inside the files, you can't do that on Github. It doesn't understand .docx files (that's why it calls them "binary files" which is a generic designation).

You can either go with text files that Gitub can handle, or do the merges locally (after downloading from Github) using Microsoft Word itself.

Comment: Thank you, I will not go on with this solution, but simply merge the files as you suggested.